# Microsoft Access: How to merge rows and sum values

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-office-2016

Sorry if this is an amateur question, I am pretty new to Access but couldn't find this answer elsewhere.

I have 8 tables indexed by branch codes, each with 12 columns for amount sold during each month of the year.

```
Branch | January | February ...
GA01     1200.00   650.00
GA02     7000.00   50.00
```

50 or so of the branches are merging, so I need to combine the branch code (GA01 would become GA02) and sum each month under GA02. Result would be:

```
Branch | January | February ...
GA02     8200.00    700.00
```

I have tried using an update query to update the branch code, then group by branch codes. However, that gives me a query, when really I want to edit the table. Is it best to make the query as a new table and delete the old table?

Answer (score 0):

OK you've created the GROUP BY query that gives you the SUM for each month.

For reference, name this qryBranchTotals

Now create one more query, we are going to save this one as "qryBranchTotalsMakeTable"

Drop in your qryBranchTotals as the data source

Drop all the rows into the Query-By-Example grid columns at the bottom of the query editor

Run the query, make sure it looks like the data you are expecting to see.

Now change the query type to "Make Table"

Enter the name of the new table that gets created
e.g.  tblBranchTotalsCalculated

Save and Run/Execute qryBranchTotalsMakeTable

Viola!  Now you have now created a new table where you can edit the data
tblBranchTotalsCalculated